# Python: Iterate over unique combinations in a list

Tags: python

I have a list that contains 16 unique numbers:

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,...,16]
```

I want to iterate over all possible combinations of 4 of the numbers, eg:

```
iterate1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
iterate2 = [1, 2, 3, 5]
iterate3 = [1, 2, 3, 6]
.
.
.
```

Numbers in the list cannot repeat.

Comment: No, as long as all combinations are considered in the end.

Comment: Should I delete my question since it is a duplicate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want itertools

```
import itertools
list(itertools.permutations([1,2,3...16],4)
```

**EDIT**

Or if you actually need the combination function, just use that.

```
import itertools
list(itertools.combinations([1,2,3...16],4)
```

Comment: There is a key difference between permutations and combinations.

Comment: From his question, it seems he wants permutations

Comment: Given that his question title and body use the word _combination_, I disagree.

Comment: Most people use "combinations" as a generic term, rather than it's strict mathematical meaning, though I'm sure Mike could clear it up.

Comment: Down votes without explanation aren't very helpful.

Comment: This is an extremely common duplicate to which your answer provides no further value than the answers on the linked duplicate question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158111/discussion-between-superstew-and-miradulo).

Comment: I didn't downvote. Still, you have two syntax errors in your examples.

Comment: If you mean "..." yea I figured Mike would know what to do there. Otherwise, those lines worked for me.

Comment: Thank you @SuperStew. I did indeed meen permutations, thank you for giving both. And I did also understand `...` (-;

Comment: *No*, those lines certainly didn't work for you. Notice the `)` missing?

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools
i = 1
print i
for x in itertools.combinations(range(1,16), 4) :
    print "iterate" + str(i) + " = " +  str(x)
    i = i + 1
```